# Memory Cache and Threads

Tags: c#, .net, memorycache, asp.net-caching

Does MemoryCache create thread for each instance of the memory cache or there is a single thread across all memory cache instances? I have a few documentations that say that the granularity of the cache is 20 seconds and every 20 seconds a thread goes over the list of items and expires items that are expired. However, I have been not able to find documentation that lists how many threads are created.

Comment: Why do you think it directly create threads rather then using `ThreadPool`?

Comment: Okay. That indirectly answers my question. I wasn't sure myself that it was using a threadpool but your question lead me to do further research on Timer class which uses a threadpool.